# LIKE mysql query for complete words

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table having 2000 categories.I want to search words by LIKE search. I want to get all MEN related categories

```
SELECT * FROM `inf_levelthree` WHERE l3_name LIKE '%men%'
```

It also show me wrong result like

```
Department Store

Women Textiles
```

and so on which is not related to **men**

What can i do so that i can get all having men only like below

```
Fashion - Men
Men Fashion
Mens Fashion
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you can add one more condition " and not like '%women%'"

Comment: Its not only %women%..this was just an example..it also show many others like 'Entertainment'..then what i will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM `inf_levelthree` 
            WHERE l3_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]men[[:>:]]'
               or l3_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]mens[[:>:]]' ;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a75d8/4)

Comment: It is not matter of men or mens..this was just an example...user will type anything they want.

Comment: @Muhammad  If you need to find a WORD you can use `l3_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]WORD[[:>:]]'` this template finds a WORD enclosed with spaces or in the end (or in the start) of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Add Spaces to your Pattern

```
SELECT * FROM `inf_levelthree` WHERE l3_name LIKE '% men%' OR l3_name LIKE '%men %'
```

This will only select those complete words which either Start with `Men` or end at `Men`